# Can I embed iframe from my site using chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I create chrome extension. When user hits special shortcut this extension will add iframe to current active page in chrome. This iframe will load js from external resource (my site) and show some data. Is this allowed (to load external js inside iframe)?

I did not find any restrictions in chrome developers about that, but I worry if my extension will not pass check at chrome webstore.

Comment: I guess it depends on which permissions your extensions has because once the external script is compromised, it'll have access to everything your extension has access to. Generally, this is A Very Bad Idea.

Answer (score -1):

You can insert any HTML code into the DOM, but if you're inserting an IFRAME, it will be limited by same-origin restrictions which will likely prevent the embedded Javascript from running unless both websites share a common domain and protocol.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy for further details.